# Формирование url в CMS

Tags: php, cms

У Flexo CMS, frogcms, wolfcms одна и та же проблема (одна cms, разные вариации) - одна страница доступна по адресам: site/example, site/example/, site/example.html

А в архиве страницы доступны по таким адресам: site/example, site/2000/01/01/example, site/2000/01/01/example.html

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой? Если слеш / на конце можно поправить в .htaccess, то архив надо править в исходнике. Кто-нибудь может по-быстренькому помочь?

Comment: В конфиге есть константа URL_SUFFIX  со значением '.html', попробуй заменить на пустую строку.